# Redis Elasticache Cache Management

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have a question regarding Redis elasticate cache management. In the past, I have used the terracotta management console or Ehcache cli to clear particular keys, and also clear the entire cache cluster.

My application requires frequent cache clear for some of the keys. Rebooting the entire cache cluster is not an option.

- Has anyone come across this scenario?
- Has anyone used GUI tools like Redis desktop manager or redsmin which can do this task?

Comment: are you using aws elasticache?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any standard redis client can be used with AWS elasticache